# Check if NSRect is null

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm not able to check if a NSRect structure has a value.

```
if(!myRect)// produce an error
if(myRect== nil) //this's not a pointer...can't works.
```

Which is the correct way ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the `NSIsEmptyRect` function is more comfortable, right?
If you just want to check with the zero rect.

Answer (score 10):

An `NSRect` is a struct, not a pointer, and therefor it can't be `nil` or `NULL`. You can however check if a rect is equal to `NSZeroRect` with `if(NSEqualRects(myRect, NSZeroRect))`.

Comment: With NSZeroRect i check if myRect is equal to `{ { 0.0, 0.0 } , { 0.0, 0.0 } }` i need to check if a struct is initialized not if is equal to zero value.

Comment: Unlike in RDBMSs, there is no intrinsic "invalid" value for memory. NULL is simply 0, which is given a special significance when it's the value of a pointer; but there is no such thing for integers (0 is just another integer) or for structs, unless you choose one yourself. NSZeroRect would be a sensible choice.

Comment: Since the components of a rectangle are floating-point numbers, you can use NaN as its components, and write a function that tests `isnan` on each of the rectangle's members. (Testing equality won't work: NaN is inequal not only to every number, but also to NaN itself!)